# Showing an alert dialog in a translucent activity

Tags: android, service, android-alertdialog

So I have a service from which I am trying to show an alert dialog. This seems to be impossible so I decided to show it in the translucent activity of my application. However, I am getting this error:

```
02-01 10:29:18.336 3806-3806/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.application.sweetiean.dummylocationupdates, PID: 3806
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.application.sweetiean.dummylocationupdates/com.application.sweetiean.dummylocationupdates.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:355)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:324)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onPostCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:172)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:101)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPostCreate(Instrumentation.java:1186)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Here is my main activity class:

```
package com.application.sweetiean.dummylocationupdates;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.view.ContextThemeWrapper;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import static com.application.sweetiean.dummylocationupdates.R.style.dialog;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Background Services starting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // use this to start and trigger a service
    Intent i= new Intent(this, LocationUpdateService.class);
    /*this.startService(i);
    finish();*/

    // potentially add data to the intent
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    // check if enabled and if not send user to the GSP settings
    if (!enabled) {
        showSettingsAlert();
    } else {
        this.startService(i);
        finish();
    }
    //finish();
}

public void showSettingsAlert() {
    //AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getApplication(), dialog));
    builder.setTitle("GPS Settings");
    builder.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to enable it?");
    //AlertDialog alert =  builder.create();

    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            //stopSelf();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alert =  builder.create();

    alert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);

    alert.show();

}
```

}

I am using the fused location provider API in my service and I want to ensure that the user turns on their GPS before the service runs.
I have this in my manifest already: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />`

**NOT ENTIRELY RELATED QUESTION BUT IT WOULD BE ELATED TO GET AN ANSWER**
What is the Google PlayStore's policy on apps that run location services all day? Since I am using the FusedLocationProvider API will the playstore reject my app because the requires the GPS to be running all day whether it is in the foreground or the background or even if the app is killed

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this :

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            MainActivity.this);
  builder.setTitle("GPS Settings");
  builder.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to enable it?");
  AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
  alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: I am still getting the same logcat error with this. Requesting me to use an AppCompat Theme

Comment: @SweetieAnang try the updated answer. Let me know if this works

Comment: It did not change anything. My MainActivity is a translucent activity

Comment: Apparently, I'm using the same code to display dialog in translucent activity.

Comment: What is the theme of your translucent activity?

Comment: parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

You can also try setting this theme and calling this code to set acitivity translucent : getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134583/discussion-between-sweetie-anang-and-basu-singh).

Answer (score 1):

For the first `exception` try this:

create this theme in your `styles.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
```

use this as:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
</activity>
```

For the second inquiry i don't think it will create a problem for ur app in google play..

but it is best practice to stop all background services when app is destroyed

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Using Theme.AppCompat defeats my purpose for maintaining a translucent theme :( That is why I want to fix the code to enable the alertDialog to show whiles ignoring the logcat suggestion.   As for my second enquiry, thank you for the input. this means on onDestroy, I should disconnect my service right?

Comment: here is a good example:http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/10/fused-location-provider-in-android.html

Comment: Hahahaha this is the exact tutorial I used since it is my first time using the FusedLocationProvider API!!! It is a great one, helped me understand it better than the google docs

Comment: Almost there now. So, I cannot call MainActivity.finish() after the user clicks Yes. Because of this, the back button comes back to the activity. Also the service's onStartCommand method is not called after the user turns the GPS on

Comment: you need to call startservice method in your activity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134595/discussion-between-sweetie-anang-and-rafsanahmad007).

Answer (score 0):

From the log

Unable to start activity java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

try Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant)

also in this scenario avoid using fused location instead use Location Manager

LocationManager  manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

Comment: Why would you suggest I use LocationManager, what is the advantage over FusedLocation. I was using Location Manager before and switched to the google play services api. Also, can I use an appcompat theme with a translucent activity? I only started getting this error when i decided to introduce the alertdialog